# Magento 2.1.6 to 2.1.7 Upgrade Issues Or Latest version

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7, magento2-migration-tool, magento2.1.6

I am using following commands Magento upgrade 2.1.6 to 2.1.7 and also 2.1.9

I am getting error below command run via putty,

> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 composer
>   update

```
./composer.json has been updated
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**
- Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7
- Conclusion: remove magento/framework 100.1.6
- Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 100.1.6
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 -> 
 satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.7].
 - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 100.1.6
 - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 requires magento/framework 
 100.1.7 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.7].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.6, 100.1.7].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.6, 100.1.7].
 - Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 100.1.6) -> 
 satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.6].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How to upgrade magento 2.1.6 to magento 2.1.9 or latest version

Please help me asap .

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a live site, please take backup of your database and files.

Open your composer.json file.
Under the `require` field, update the magento version to 2.2.0 as follows.

```
magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.0"
```

In your command line, enter the command to reset the sample data.

```
php bin/magento sampledata:reset
```

Now remove all the sample data modules from the composer.json file

```
"magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-customer-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/sample-data-media": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.1.*"
```

After saving the composer.json file, run the `composer update` command and at last, re install the sample data by entering the following command in the command prompt.

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Run the setup upgrade command and check your site.

Comment: Above method not working , i am getting error in magento 2 upgrading .

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: thanks for your reply ,

Edit composer.json file change the version number and run the below command via putty `php bin/magento sampledata:reset`  i am getting below error code ,

`[Exception]
  Warning: file_get_contents(sampleproject/app/cod
  e/Webspeaks/Fancyfeedback/composer.json): failed to open stream: No such fi
  le or directory in sampleproject/vendor/magento/
  module-sample-data/Model/Dependency.php on line 109



sampledata:reset`